# Using a data frame of replacement values to replace values in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of values:

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = 1:2, X2 = c(1L, 3L), X3 = 2:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

  X1 X2 X3
1  1  1  2
2  2  3  3
```

And a data frame containing replacement values:

```
replacement_values <- structure(list(num = c("1", "2", "3"), . = c("cat", 
"dog", "mouse")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

  num     .
1   1   cat
2   2   dog
3   3 mouse
```

For example, every time the number "1" is found in the first data frame, I would like it replaced by the word "cat", every time "2" is found I want it replaced by "dog" and every time "3" is found I want it replaced by "mouse".  So Ideally I would end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
    X1    X2    X3
1  cat   cat   dog
2  dog mouse mouse
```

I could do it like this but it's very long winded and doesn't use the replacement_values data frame:

```
df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        X1 = X1 %>% 
            gsub("1", "cat", .) %>%
            gsub("2", "dog", .) %>%
            gsub("3", "mouse", .),
        X2 = X2 %>% 
            gsub("1", "cat", .) %>%
            gsub("2", "dog", .) %>%
            gsub("3", "mouse", .),
        X3 = X3 %>% 
            gsub("1", "cat", .) %>%
            gsub("2", "dog", .) %>%
            gsub("3", "mouse", .)
            )
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
replacement_values <-
  structure(list(
    num = c("1", "2", "3"),
    . = c("cat",
          "dog", "mouse")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-3L),
  class = "data.frame")

df <-
  structure(list(
    X1 = 1:2,
    X2 = c(1L, 3L),
    X3 = 2:3
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-2L))

map_df(df, ~replacement_values$.[match(.x, table = replacement_values$num)])
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   X1    X2    X3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 cat   cat   dog  
#> 2 dog   mouse mouse
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could first `unlist` the values in your dataframe `df` and `match` the values from `replacement_values` with `df` like this:

```r
df[] <- replacement_values$.[match(unlist(df), replacement_values$num)]
df
#>    X1    X2    X3
#> 1 cat   cat   dog
#> 2 dog mouse mouse
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, `match` is still the best option. Use `across` to apply the change over all functions. Note that it's preferable in this case to use `function(x)` instead of the usual `~` since you have `.` as a variable name.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) replacement_values$.[match(x, replacement_values$num)]))
```

output

```r
   X1    X2    X3
1 cat   cat   dog
2 dog mouse mouse
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is to demonstrate that lapply can be useful.

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = 1:2, X2 = c(1L, 3L), X3 = 2:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df[]=lapply(df, function(x) gsub(1,"cat", x))
df[]=lapply(df, function(x) gsub(2,"dog", x))
df[]=lapply(df, function(x) gsub(3,"mouse", x))
```

the result:

```
X1  X2  X3
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>
cat cat     dog
dog mouse   mouse
```